# Integrable connections and holomorphic structures

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, almost-complex

Let $X$ be a complex manifold of complex dimension $n$ and let $(E,h)$ be a smooth Hermitian vector bundle over $X$. Then there is a correspondence between unitary connections on $(E,h)$ and almost complex structures on $E$, these identified with Dolbeault operators $\bar{\partial}_E:\Omega^0(E)\rightarrow \Omega^{0,1}(E)$.

This correspondence goes even further: **integrable** almost complex structures correspond to unitary connections such that the curvature is of type (1,1), $F_A^{2,0}=F_A^{0,2}=0$.

I want to verify the following: in Riemann surfaces $n=1$, every almost complex structure on $E$ is integrable (i.e. a holomorphic structure), since there are no non-trivial (0,2) or (2,0) forms over a Riemann surface. Is this correct or am I making a horrible mistake somewhere? I feel that should be explicitly stated in the books that I am working with but they seem to overlook this (or maybe it is completely false!)

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the correspondence in the first paragraph? How are you identifying an almost complex structure on $E$, which is a real linear map $J : E \to E$ satisfying $J\circ J = -\operatorname{id}_E$, with a map $\Omega(E) \to \Omega^{0,1}(E)$?